# Efficiently Interpolating along one dimension of a 5D Matrix

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, interpolation

The following code does what I need and I cannot figure out a more efficient way to do this. Basically I only need to interpolate along 1 dimension of a 5D matrix. Can someone please enlighten me on how to do this in MATLAB more efficiently? Thanks!

```
    % Define Parameters
    BETA = 11000;
    Desired_SOC = 0.55; 
    u1_length = 15;
    u2_length = 3;
    u3_length = 2;
    x2_length = 2;
    x3_length = 6;
    x1_grid = [0.4:0.05:0.8]'; 

    % Not really my data, but it will sufice
    table_x1 = repmat(x1_grid,[1, x2_length,x3_length,u1_length,u2_length,u3_length]);
    J_STAR = BETA*(x1_grid - Desired_SOC).^2;

    tic;
    SOC_State_Penalty = single(zeros(x1_length,x2_length,x3_length,u1_length,u2_length,u3_length)); 
   for x2 = 1:x2_length
        for x3 = 1:x3_length
            for u1 = 1:u1_length
                 for u2 = 1:u2_length
                      for u3 = 1:u3_length
                        F  = griddedInterpolant(x1_grid,J_STAR(:,x2,x3),'linear');  % Just need to penalize the SOC
                        SOC_State_Penalty(:,x2,x3,u1,u2,u3) = F(table_x1(:,x2,x3,u1,u2,u3));
                      end
                 end
            end
        end
     end
    toc;
```

Comment: `reshape` to a 1d vector, use `interp1` on the proper block size, and `reshape` back?

Comment: Using `interpn` with `X2`=`Xq2` to `Xn`=`Xqn` should the same, or I am unable to read your code.

Comment: Thanks fellas! Sorry if it is confusing. I tried interpn, but it did not work. Basically my code is interpolating along the x1 direction for all combinations of x2, x3, u1, u2, and u3. Also, this code is actually nested into another for loop, so each time it comes back into the loop it has a new J_STAR. So, J_STAR is where my penalty data for the states (x's) is defined and my table_x1 is has all of the data that I want to assign penalty's to.